# How to stop Swagger UI from loading Petstore

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I've been updating my company's projects to the latest versions of all the packages.  When I try to run swagger (`http://localhost:4000/swagger/?url=/swagger/swagger.json`), it now redirects me to the Petstore.

After searching Google for an answer, it seems like I need to set the following parameter:

```
queryConfigEnabled=true
```

According to the Swagger documentation, I can set the parameter in the following ways:

> Swagger UI accepts configuration parameters in four locations.
>
> From lowest to highest precedence:
>
> - The `swagger-config.yaml` in the project root directory, if it exists,    is baked into the application
> - configuration object passed as an argument to Swagger UI (`SwaggerUI({ ... })`)
> - configuration document fetched from a specified `configUrl`
> - configuration items passed as key/value pairs in the URL query string

I tried the following URL

```
http://localhost:4000/swagger/?queryConfigEnabled=true&url=http://localhost:4000/swagger/swagger.json
```

but that still redirected me to the Petstore.

I then tried to create a `swagger-config.yaml` file in the project root directory with the following contents:

```
queryConfigEnabled: "true"
url: "/swagger/swagger.json"
dom_id: "#swagger-ui"
validatorUrl: "https://validator.swagger.io/validator"
```

That didn't work either.  I even tried to copy the config file to the project `/src` folder to see if that made a difference.

I tried other things like using a `swagger-config.json` file instead, copying the config file to the app root in the docker image, setting the `configURL` to point to the config file, setting the docker environment `CONFIG_URL` to point to the swagger config file.  None of these solutions worked.  I'm still being redirected to the Petstore.

As a last resort, I modified the `dist/swagger-initializer.js` file and added the `queryConfigEnabled` parameter.

That worked.

Obviously, if I delete the `/node_modules` folder and re-run `npm install`, that change will go away.

What am I doing wrong?  How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you use Swagger UI's `dist` assets directly, or is your Swagger UI provided by some npm package (such as `swagger-jsdoc`, `swagger-ui-express`, `swagger-ui-react`)?

Comment: I'm loading the `swagger-ui-dist` npm package and calling `npx swaggerGen` to build the swagger.json file.